# Cardinality of well-formed formulae on a multi-sorted signature

Tags: logic, first-order-logic, predicate-logic, cardinals

I had some questions regarding the cardinality of the sets of well-formed formulae and terms on a multi-sorted signature. I will give first the usual definitions.

A *signature* Σ is a triple〈S;F;R〉 where:

- S is a (non-empty) set of *symbols for types*;
- F is a set of *symbols for functions* (each symbol f∈F is associated with a type s1×···×sn→s0, where si∈S for every 0≤i≤n (in particular, when n=0 we say that f is a *constant symbol*);
- R is a (non-empty) set of *relation symbols*. Each symbol r∈R is only associated with a type s1×···×sn, where si∈S for every 1≤i≤n. When n=0 we say that r is a *propositional constant*;
- S∩F∩R = ∅

For simplicity, from now on, we assume only signatures with at least one non-0-ary relation symbol (otherwise we would fall back into non-first-order languages).

We define terms and formulae inductively in this way.

Let Σ =〈S;F;R〉be a signature and let *Var* be a set of symbols, called variables, such that Var∩(S∪F∪R) = ∅. We assume that each variable x∈Var has a uniquely associated type s∈S, and use the notation x:s to indicate that the variable x is of type s. We also make sure that there is a countably infinite quantity of variables for each type s∈S (that is, |Var|=|S|•ℵ0).

Given a signature Σ =〈S;F;R〉and a set of variables Var, a *term* and its relative type on 〈Σ; Var〉 are inductively defined in this way:

- if x:s∈Var then x is a term of type s;
- if f:s1×···×sn→s0∈F and t1,...,tn are terms respectively of type s1,...,sn then f(t1, ..., tn) is a term of type s0.

Well-formed formulas are instead defined like this:
Given a signature Σ =〈S;F;R〉 and a set of variables Var, a *well-formed formula* on〈Σ; Var〉is inductively defined as:

- if r:s1×···×sn∈R is a relation symbol and t1:s1,...,tn:sn are terms then r(t1, ..., tn) is a well-formed formula;
- if A and B are well-formed formulas, then ¬A, A∧B, A∨B, and A→B are well-formed formulas;
- if x:s is a variable and A is a well-formed formula, then ∀x:s.A and ∃x:s.A are well-formed formulas.

Let Ter(〈Σ;Var〉) and Var(〈Σ;Var〉) be the sets, respectively, of the terms and of the well-formed formulae on〈Σ;Var〉.

I was wondering if these two propositions hold true:

1. |Ter(〈Σ;Var〉)|=max(|F|,|S|•ℵ0)
2. |For(〈Σ;Var〉)|=max(|Σ|,|S|•ℵ0) where |Σ|:=|S|+|F|+|R| (assuming that in R there is at least one non-0-ary relation symbol).

Does somebody have a hint on how to prove them, if they indeed are correct? Thanks a lot.

Comment: Are you constraining $\text{Var}$ to be infinite?

Comment: Yes, I am. I am also constraining the variables for each type to be countably infinite.

Comment: so I did the dumb thing and made a pair of encodings and invoked Cantor-Schröder-Bernstein. In order to get this encoding to work, we need our *alphabet* for terms to be infinite, otherwise we can't prepend the length of the string and "compress our way down" to a single letter. Having $\text{Var}$ be infinite is enough to get this argument to work, I think.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are two strategies for proving that two sets have the same cardinality.

- Construct an explicit bijection.
- Construct a pair of injections and invoke the [Cantor-Schröder-Bernstein theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schr%C3%B6der%E2%80%93Bernstein_theorem).

Let's look at the first example.

First, we'll assume that $\text{Var}$ is infinite, as is commonly done.

I claim that $|\text{Term}(\Sigma, \text{Var})|$ is $\max(|F|, |S|, |\text{Var}|)$.

To prove $\ge$, take the terms and well-order them and do the same to the symbols on the right. Associate to each symbol the first term that isn't associated with any previous symbol. This gives us an injection from the right to the left.

To prove $\le$.

Let $L \sup F \cup S \cup \text{Var}$ be the set of all symbols including improper symbols like $($, $,$, and $)$. Note that there are finitely many improper symbols.

Since $|\text{Term}(\Sigma, \text{Var})|$ is infinite, there's a map $n \mapsto i(n)$ from the natural numbers to $L$.

Also, since $L$ is infinite, there's an injection from $L \times L$ to $(F \cup S \cup \text{Var})$. Let's call the injection $(x, y) \mapsto [x, y]$.

A term is a sequence of symbols $l_1, l_2, l_3, \cdots$ of symbols taken from $L$.

Let's encode it as $[i(n), [t_1, [t_2, [t_3, \cdots]]]]$.

This gives us an injection into $(F \cup S \cup \text{Var})$.

Now we invoke Cantor-Schröder-Bernstein and conclude that the same sets have the same cardinality.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I get why you want to use the Cantor-Schröder-Bernstein theorem, which is the simple usual way to prove that there is a bijection between two sets. The problem I have is with the injection from Ter(Σ;Var) to S∪F∪Var. There is something here that isn't clear to me...

Comment: I inject the terms (strings) into single letters by first prefixing them with the length of the string ... and then compressing the string into a single letter working from right to left and ending with the length. This is all above board because the string is finitely long. There's an injection from $L^2$ to $F \cup S \cup \text{Var}$. $L$ is just that plus the improper symbols.

Comment: If I call L*=L∪L²∪L³∪... isn't the main point that there is a bijection between L* and L, and hence - since there is an injection between Terms and L* and since there is a bijection between L and S∪F∪Var (since L just is S∪F∪Var plus a finite number of other symbols) - that there is an injection between Terms and S∪F∪Var?

Comment: Yes, I think what you're saying is right. What I was doing amounts to proving the $|L^*| \le |L|$ step explicitly. However, if you already have that result for arbitrary infinite alphabets, then just using it is fine.

Comment: Yes, thank you very much. Now I think I get it and I also get your coding technique as an explicit proof of |L*|≤|L|.